# Skip execution of a maven plugin if a file does not exist in the project

Tags: maven, plugins, profile

I want to skip executing a plugin when a certain file does not exist. Is there a way to do it?

```
<plugin>                           
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>             
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
    <version>1.8</version>                                 
    <executions>                                            
        <execution>                                            
            <id>add-test-source</id>                   
                <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>            
                <goals>                                      
                    <goal>add-test-source</goal>               
                </goals>                                
                <configuration>                               
                    <sources>                   
                        <source>${customFolder}</source>     
                    </sources>                         
                </configuration>                           
        </execution>                                      
    </executions>                                             
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surround the plugin definition with profile.

Profiles can be activated depending on the existence/non-existence of a file.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: I want the above plugin to execute only when cuts file is present so how do I surround it with profile. I'm getting error when I place profile.

Comment: Sorry, there is nothing "below". Please edit the question and add the information there.

Comment: 1. Please don't paste XML into comments, instead edit the question. 2. Please wrap it in a profile. If this does not work, report the exact error message.

Comment: So, what happens when you wrap it into a profile?

Comment: When I'm doing it at <profiles> there's a compiler error shown in STS. It's not displaying what the error is except for red cross symbol.

Comment: Then run the build and report the error that is shown in the console.

Comment: Thanks, solved the error. Now there's no error. What should be the condition for activation of profile?

Comment: You need a `<missing>` tag as described in the linked document.

Comment: Solved the issue. Everything is fine now. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have one more question.. In my pom.xml I have a plugin which generates a file. Now I want to activate my profile based on this. When do it I have to do maven install 2 times to get desired result. The first my necessary file is being generated and in second run the profile is getting activated. Can do it in single step?

Comment: You cannot activate a profile based on a file you create during the build. But of course, there may be other ways to achieve the result you want. You probably need to write a new question for that.